# Woocommerce Variations Displayed on Archive Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got some code working perfectly on my single product pages. For some reason, it will not function the same in archive/list view.

First, I used a plugin to make the variations radio buttons instead of the dropdown. Then I modified that and made it display the price of each variation. Like I said, works great on product page.

I'm new at this google and compile until my eyes bleed and eventually it works. No such luck this time.

Here is the product page: http://pchdelivery.com/product/star-wars-kush/
Here is archive: http://pchdelivery.com/menu/

I don't need any of the cart functionality, only to display the variations and respective price with each product in categories.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As per I can understand the issue, you may need to change the settings from the attribute options for the product where you will have to choose the option to not shown in product archive pages.

Screenshot : http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2352336/b6552a6b4d83f8c16efd5935046728c4

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is not the issue however. My php query has the value I need in each, it just also includes a lot of other code I don't want. My goal is to filter out that extra junk and display it clean as it does on the product page linked above.